# How to detect if a string is Base64Encoded or not?

Tags: delphi, encoding, character-encoding

Which is the best method to detect if a string is Base64Encoded or not (using Delphi)?

Answer (score 5):

Best you can do is try to decode it. If the decode fails then the input was not base64 encoded. It the string successfully decodes then the input **might** have been base64 encoded.

Comment: this will depend how the component or function used to decode was implemented, for example if you uses the `TIdDecoderMIME` component of Indy to decode a invalid Base64 string the component does not raise any exceptio or error.

Comment: @RRUZ Good point. Most important point to get across though is that just because a string can be decoded, doesn't mean it was originally encoded.

Answer (score 5):

You can check if the string only contains [Base64 valids chars](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc4648.html)

```
function StringIsBase64(const InputString : String ) : Boolean;
const
  Base64Chars: Set of AnsiChar = ['A'..'Z','a'..'z','0'..'9','+','/','='];
var
  i : integer;
begin
  Result:=True;
   for i:=1 to Length(InputString) do
   {$IFDEF UNICODE}
   if not CharInSet(InputString[i],Base64Chars) then
   {$ELSE}
   if not (InputString[i] in Base64Chars) then
   {$ENDIF}
   begin
     Result:=False;
     break;
   end;
end;
```

The `=` char is used for padding so you can add an aditional valiation to the function for padded base64 strings checking if the length of the string is mod 4

Comment: +1, though proving the reverse may be a better concept - i.e if the string contains characters outside the valid range, then it is NOT Base64, otherwise it may or may noth be,  as discussed in other answers.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to RRUZ answer you can also check the length of the string (is it a multiple of 4).

```
function IsValidBase64(const aValue: string): Boolean;
var
  i: Integer;
  lValidChars: set of Char;
begin
  Result := aValue <> '';
  lValidChars := ['a'..'z', 'A'..'Z', '0'..'9', '/', '+'];
  //length of string should be multiple of 4
  if Length(aValue) mod 4 > 0 then
    Result := False
  else
    for i := 1 to Length(aValue) do
    begin
      if aValue[i] = '=' then
      begin
        if i < Length(aValue) - 1 then
        begin              
          Result := False;
          Exit;
        end
        else
          lValidChars := ['='];
      end
      else if not (aValue[i] in lValidChars) then
      begin
        Result := False;
        Break;
      end;
    end;
end;
```

Please note that this code is Delphi 7 code and not adjusted for Unicode use.

Comment: Even then it is only a good guess. It isn't strange for 'random' strings to pass this test and not being Base64.

Comment: @Lars The function would be better named `MightBeBase64`

Comment: @Lars Truijens: Yes, you are right. If you really want to do this right, you should check if the `=` only exists at the end and only one or two of them.

Comment: @The_Fox Checking for correct terminating `=` changes nothing. Plenty of random strings would pass this test and yet decode to gobbledegook.

Comment: @David Heffernan: yes, you are right, I changed the name of the function to reflect this. This function only checks if the string is a valid base64 string, it doesn't guarantee the contents. That should be the responsibility of the programmer.

Comment: @The_Fox, you should treat the `=` sign char as invalid when it's *inside* of a string.

Comment: @The_Fox, not as well as could be. That doesn't compile due to assigning a char to the `lValidChars`, but anyway, you still consider an empty string as valid ;-)

Comment: @TLama: that sometimes happens when you do a quick edit from a laptop with kids running around :)

Answer (score 4):

As was already told here, there is no reliable verification if a certain string is Base64 encoded or not, so even when you consider the input as a valid Base64 encoded string, it doesn't mean the string is actually encoded that way. I'm posting here just another version of a validation function, which according to [`RFC 4648`](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4648.txt) verifies:

- if the input string is not empty and its length is multiple of 4
- if the input string contains at most two padding characters and only at the end of the string
- if the input string contains only characters from the Base64 alphabet (see the [`Page 5, Table 1`](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4648.txt))

```
function IsValidBase64EncodedString(const AValue: string): Boolean;
const
  Base64Alphabet = ['A'..'Z', 'a'..'z', '0'..'9', '+', '/'];
var
  I: Integer;
  ValLen: Integer;
begin
  ValLen := Length(AValue);
  Result := (ValLen > 0) and (ValLen mod 4 = 0);
  if Result then
  begin
    while (AValue[ValLen] = '=') and (ValLen > Length(AValue) - 2) do
      Dec(ValLen);
    for I := ValLen downto 1 do
      if not (AValue[I] in Base64Alphabet) then
      begin
        Result := False;
        Break;
      end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: P.S. `downto` iteration I've used here because of suspecting possible 3rd `=` sign char at the end of the string.

Comment: +1. I think that `IsValidBase64EncodedString` is better name than `CanBe...`. because after all, it *does* indicate that the input string is in fact a valid base64 encoded string.