# How to insert a string containing #0 in a NVARCHAR() column in MSSQL?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, delphi, delphi-xe2, ado

I'm sure this has a very simple solution, but I've exhausted my resources. I need to insert a bunch of `WideString` variables which may contain `#0` into a `NVARCHAR(1024)` column in MSSQL2k8. `#0` is treated as the string terminator somewhere in the transition... So, when I store `#6'r'#0'abc'`, only `#6'r'` is stored. I'm using `TADOQuery`. What can I do about this?

---

Here's the code I use:

```
var
  S: string;
begin
  S := #6'r'#0'abc';
  ADOQuery1.Append;
  ADOQuery1S.Value := S;
  { At this point, S = #6'r'#0'abc' and ADOQuery1S.Value = #6'r';}
  ADOQuery1.Post;
end;
```

Comment: @iManBiglari - Is there no escape character in delphi to treat it as constant instead of string terminator?

Comment: @SachinShanbhag Delphi _shouldn't_ treat the null character as the string terminator. Local variables correctly handle #0 in the middle of a string.

Comment: @TLama I'm writing some password into the DB, and just XOR it with the user name before writing, so that the passwords won't be saved in the plain. I'm considering using a real encryption here, but wanted to see if there was a way to save me a few hours of work

Comment: Delphi itself doesn't care about NULLs in the middle of a string - it has a "known length" of up to 2147483647 characters. However, if using ADO it is probably passing through an C based API that treats it as a terminator. Also if using Xe2, strings are unicode, so there will be two consecutive nulls in the memory block.

Comment: @TLama - it doesn't care, #0 is just another character. Delphi strings handle nulls without problems, unless they are passed to an API that treats them as terminators. Delphi strings are effectively dynamic arrays of char. Of course most Windows API's do treat them as terminators.\

Comment: I don't know enough about the tech to make this an answer, but moving from passing a string to passing a byte array would surely fix the problem.

Comment: @TLama My best guess is that somewhere in the transition to ADO API, the string is copied into a PChar and thus truncated at #0

Comment: Don't do this. NVARCHAR is not suitable for binary data. if you want to encrypt a password and save a binary result, at least use base64 (or other)  to encode it to a string.

Comment: @kobik Am I wrong to suppose NVARCHAR can contain any character from 0x0000 to 0xFFFF?

Comment: Have you tried setting using  `ADOQuery1S.AsString := S;` instead of .Value? It may be a problem with Variants rather than ADO.

Comment: @iman NVARCHAR is ucs-2 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx). From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16: "Both UTF-16 and UCS-2 encode code points in the range U+0000 to U+FFFF as single 16-bit code units that are numerically equal to the corresponding code points. The code points in the BMP are the only code points that can be represented in UCS-2." Strictly speaking not *all* code points in that range are defined, see e.g. the table defined at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Multilingual_Plane#Basic_Multilingual_Plane - there are some gaps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to store an string encrypted by any means that could have NULLs in it, encode and decode the encrypted data as Base64 using the routines in Soap.EncdDecd.pas (EncdDecd.pas in older versions).

And **DO USE** proper encryption, either from Microsoft CryptoAPI, or any of the native Delphi implementations such as [DCPCrypt](http://www.cityinthesky.co.uk/opensource/dcpcrypt).

If you are storing passwords for access to your system, consider hashing (and salting) them instead. Obviously if they are passwords to connect to other systems you can't do that.

```
var
  B64: string;
begin
  B64 := EncodeString(#6'r'#0'abc');
  ADOQuery1.Append;
  ADOQuery1S.Value := B64;
  ADOQuery1.Post;
end;
```

Comment: Unfortunately hash is out of the question, as I need the passwords themselves to pass to some _very_ poor designed software. Now, just one question. Consider I have a string. How can I determine if it is _encoded_ or not using the `EncdDecd` functions?

Comment: @iManBiglari, if a string is Base64 encoded or not [`you can only guess`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6895009/960757).

Comment: Never mind... Figured an easy way to put a * at the beginning of the encoded strings and remove it before decoding

Answer (score 2):

If you can change the schema, use VARBINARY or IMAGE instead.
These field types are designed to hold binary data.

```
create table MY_DATA ( FLD_1 varbinary(2048), FLD_2 image )
```